# It's 2018 and I start to care about Internet Explorer 5.5

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, optimization

I don't know if I should ask this here, but I really need your opinion.

I read and read many online articles about why you should don't care about old Internet Explorer versions (because it is really outdated and insecure etc). I have taken seriously all those articles and I started to don't care about Internet Explorer <= 11 when I redesigned and re-launched my websites.

Now, it's 2018 and I need to re-design my websites and add new features (because I got a lot of user feedback, and I have a lot of exciting ideas). And because I start it from the beginning I want to think again about this. I analyzed my stats and I'm still getting hits from IE8, **IE7**, **IE6** and... IE**5.5** (Windows **98 & ME**)!

I know these versions are really outdated, insecure, but there are some people using old versions and old operating systems. I know I shouldn't care about these versions, but **I really care about my visitors and their experience on my website** (maybe there are people who live in the mountains or in poor villages, and they have a dial-up connection - why not?).

If there are such kind of persons, then:

1. Is there any reason why should I not create my new website to work even in Internet Explorer 5.5?
2. Why should I not care about webpage size, to be loaded fast even on dial-up or low broadband (Cable, GPRS etc)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not generally a bad idea to consider IE when creating a new website, but there are some aspects you must consider.

You should do extra work to support IE, which includes more **time** and **effort** in the development. So you must ask yourself, is it really worth it?

Also you might ignore a lot of new APIs and features of JavaScript and CSS, to support older versions of IE. So you are probably affecting user experience of a large amount of your users, for a small section of them which are using IE.
Or you might use some libraries to detect browser support for certain features or using conditional comments (again, extra work to do).

Another solution might be to show a specific page to the IE users and encourage them to use a newer browser, which probably has no effect to a person who is still using IE5 in 2018!

Generally I think there is no complete answer to this question. It really depends on the goal, time and budget of the project.